# Alternative strategies for Optimization

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods

I have a function F(x,y) and a constraint G(x,y), I am trying to maximize F but the normal Lagrange Multiplier method can't be solved analytically; it's too complicated, even for mathematica.  Are there other strategies for doing this?  Also I have an idea about the answer.  Is it possible to prove this is a maximum through other means?

Comment: Why don't you try numerical optimization software, e.g. fmincon in MATLAB?

Comment: If numerical optimization is not an option for you, then you certainly needs to say somewhat more about your problem! As is is stated, it is to broad.

Comment: There is nothing that can be said in this generality. What kind of functions are $F$ and $G$?